# Android: My spinner is not being displayed as expected

Tags: android, android-spinner

Here is all of the code that I am using to create my spinner.  This is what I am expecting the spinner to look like:

[image]

Instead I am just getting a spinner that does not have the drop down arrow and it is just a brown box.

```
<style name="spinner_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Spinner

```
 <Spinner
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonWednesday"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    style="@style/spinner_style"/>
```

Drawable

```
<item><layer-list>
    <item><shape>
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#B3BBCC" android:startColor="#E8EBEF" android:type="linear" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
    </shape></item>
    <item ><bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
    </item>
</layer-list></item>
```

Comment: Don't know about the spinner itself, but your `android:popupBackground` is not set to a valid hex color code